# Incremental adding in sql select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where customer transactions are stored in this format:

```
Account  Tran_type  Tran_Amount  tran_particular Tran_date
165266      C        5000        deposit          19_SEP-2014
165266      D        3000        withdrawal       20-SEP-2014
165266      C        8000        Deposit          21-SEP-2014
```

I am attempting to extract the Information for a Statement like this:

```
select tran_date, tran_particular,
(case when tran_type = 'C' then tran_amt else 0 end) CREDIT,
(case when tran_type = 'D' then tran_amt else 0 end) DEBIT 
from tran_table order bby tran_date asc;
```

Is there a wat to add the Balance column on each row so it would show the Balance after the Transaction? say:

```
 DATE       DESC        CREDIT DEBIT  BALANCE
19-SEP-2014 DEPOSIT     5000   0      5000
20-SEP-2014 WITHDRAWAL         3000   2000
21-SEP-2014 DEPOSIT     8000   0      10000
```

Please assist.

***EDIT*** I have trie the aswers suggested but it seems my balance is tagged to the date. See the output I have currently:

[image]

See the Balance does not change until the date changes.

Comment: I can't seem to understand the mathematics here. But you can select ex "(column1 - column2) BALANCE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tran_date, tran_particular, Credit, Debit, 
       SUM(Delta) OVER (ORDER BY tran_date) AS Balance
from
(
  select tran_date, tran_particular, 
  Case Tran_Type
    When 'C' THEN Tran_Amount
    Else 0
  End AS Credit,
  Case Tran_Type
    When 'D' THEN Tran_Amount
    Else 0
  End AS Debit,
  Case Tran_Type
    When 'C' THEN Tran_Amount
    When 'D' THEN -1 * Tran_Amount
    Else 0
  End AS Delta
  from TRANSACTIONS
  order by tran_date
)
```

Should do it

Comment: I am getting `ORA-00904: "BALANCE": invalid identifie`r on line 2

Comment: @Stanley Can you try now (I did not try it but I think you need a running sum)

Comment: This seem to be working with the assumption that I have one transaction per day and of different amounts because I am getting a static balance on the same day until the date changes. Attaching output sample

Comment: @does it change something if the sub query is sorted (sql updated)

Comment: Looks like it requires Completely Unique fields.. With Slight Modifications, I was Able to make it Work. Thanks. I learnt A lot.

Answer (score 0):

That will cost a sub-query:

```
SELECT tran_date, tran_particular,
(CASE when tran_type = 'C' THEN tran_amt ELSE 0 end) CREDIT,
(CASE when tran_type = 'D' THEN tran_amt ELSE 0 end) DEBIT,
(SELECT 
  SUM(CASE when type = 'C' tran_amt ELSE (-1) * tran_amt end)  
  FROM tran_table trn2
  WHERE
  trn2.Account   = trn1.Account  
  AND trn2.tran_id <= trn1.tran_id
  -- AND trn2.tran_date <= trn1.tran_date 
)
BALANCE 
FROM 
tran_table trn1 ORDER BY tran_date asc;
```

In large scale data, having such a sub-query is not recommended.
 Having a materialized view is more rational.

Comment: The Answer is tagged to the date. What happens is that if I have Many transactions on the same date, the Balance does not change until the date changes.

Comment: It seems Tran_date dose not have time part, So dose Transaction Table have an incremental ID field?

Comment: I have an Incremental id `tran_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  *,Sum( case when type ='C'
    then amount 
    else -amount 
    end ) over (ORDER BY date ROWS 
    BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW  )'Balance' 
from #tt1
```